# RSS Feed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, feed

We can find a script in javascript to RSS Feed and to support and enclosure with the pictures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this one : [Javascript RSS Reader 1.0](http://cstruter.com/downloads/download.php?downloadid=2)

Or create your own one

Comment: Error occured
Thrown Error:Access to restricted URI denied
Note: Apparently one cant read remote xml via firefox, please copy the file to your server

Putting a page from a any website that is not a result. xml

Example:
http://www.example.com/feed/category/index.rss

Comment: I want now to say : do it yourself :)

Comment: I did not understand exactly what you mean but ok
Finally there is a solution to it or not?

Comment: There is a solution, create your own rss reader in javascript should be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

zrssfeed supports media attachments using the enclosure tag and 
allow user callback function

http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/

Answer (score 0):

I have used javascript, jQuery, AngularJS, bootstrap and feednami libraries for this RSS feed reader.

1. Copy below code and save as .html file
2. Modify the rss url inside html source code.
3. Then open the html file with a web browser on any device.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>செய்திகள்</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description"
    content="சமீபத்திய செய்திகள், தலைப்புச் செய்திகள், தினசரி புதுப்பிப்புகள்,  முக்கிய செய்திகள், தமிழ் திரைப்பட செய்திகள், தமிழ் பிரபலங்களின் கிசுகிசுக்கள், latest news in tamil, headlines in tamil, daily updates, breaking news in tamil, tamil cinema, celebrity.">
  <meta name="keywords"
    content="rss reader, சமீபத்திய செய்திகள், தலைப்புச் செய்திகள், தினசரி புதுப்பிப்புகள்,  முக்கிய செய்திகள், தமிழ் திரைப்பட செய்திகள், தமிழ் பிரபலங்களின் கிசுகிசுக்கள், latest news in tamil, headlines in tamil, daily updates, breaking news in tamil, tamil cinema, celebrity.">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://static.sekandocdn.net/static/feednami/feednami-client-v1.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="fetchRssContent()">
    <!-- Content here -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h1>செய்திகள்</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3">
      <div class="col mb-4" ng-repeat="item in dataCollection | orderBy:'date':true">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" ng-alt="{{item.title}}" ng-src="{{item.posterLink}}">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{{item.link}}" target="_blank">{{item.title}}</a></h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{item.description}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
      return function (val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
      };
    });
    myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.dataCollection = [];
      $scope.feedUrls = [{ "url": "https://tamil.boldsky.com/rss/tamil-boldsky-fb.xml" },
      { "url": "https://tamil.filmibeat.com/rss/filmibeat-tamil-fb.xml" },
      { "url": "https://tamil.goodreturns.in/rss/goodreturns-fb.xml" },
      { "url": "http://feeds.feedburner.com/Hindu_Tamil_cartoon" },
      { "url": "http://feeds.feedburner.com/Hindu_Tamil_tamilnadu" },
      { "url": "http://feeds.feedburner.com/Hindu_Tamil_india" },
      { "url": "http://feeds.feedburner.com/Hindu_Tamil_world" }];
      $scope.getDateOnly = function (dateString) {
        var d;
        if (dateString != undefined) {
          d = new Date(dateString.split('T')[0]);
        }
        else {
          d = new Date();
        }
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        if (day < 10) {
          day = "0" + day;
        }
        if (month < 10) {
          month = "0" + month;
        }
        var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

        return date;
      };
      $scope.fetchRssContent = function () {
        var elemDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var flagCollectionUpdated = false;
        $.each($scope.feedUrls, function (feedIndex, item) {
          feednami.load(item.url, function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
              console.log(result.error)
            }
            else {
              if (result.feed != undefined && result.feed != null) {
                if (result.feed.entries != undefined && result.feed.entries != null) {
                  var article;
                  $.each(result.feed.entries, function (entryIndex, entry) {
                    if ($scope.getDateOnly(entry.pubdate) === $scope.getDateOnly()) {
                      article = {};
                      article.date = entry.pubdate;
                      article.title = entry.title;
                      article.description = (entry.summary.length > 0) ? entry.summary : entry.description;
                      article.link = entry.link;
                      if (entry.image.length > 0) {
                        article.posterLink = entry.image.url;
                      }
                      else if (entry.enclosures.length > 0) {
                        article.posterLink = entry.enclosures[0].url;
                      }
                      else {
                        elemDiv.innerHTML = entry.description;
                        if (elemDiv.getElementsByTagName("img").length > 0) {
                          article.posterLink = elemDiv.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
                        }
                      }
                      var existingItem = $.grep($scope.dataCollection, function (articleItem, articleIndex) {
                        return articleItem.title === article.title;
                      });
                      if (existingItem.length <= 0) {
                        $scope.dataCollection.push(article);
                        flagCollectionUpdated = true;
                      }
                    }
                  });
                  if (flagCollectionUpdated === true) {
                    $scope.$digest();
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          });
        });
      };
      setInterval($scope.fetchRssContent, 1800000);/*Default 30 minutes. Update the interval value in millisecond to adjust the feed fetch rate*/
    });    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```